# How can I handle Nothing branch of maybe monad gracefully?

Tags: haskell, option-type

```hs
data Union = F Float | I Int | S String

getUnionFromString :: String -> Union
getUnionFromString str =
    case (readMaybe str :: Maybe Int) of
        Just i  -> I i
        Nothing ->
            case (readMaybe str :: Maybe Float) of
                Just f  -> F f
                Nothing -> S str

getStr (F f) = "Float " ++ show f
getStr (I i) = "Int " ++ show i
getStr (S s) = "String " ++ s

main = do
    str <- getLine
    putStrLn $ getStr (getUnionFromString str)
```

I want to make a function that transforms string to union type(Float | Int | String). So I used `readMaybe` to find out type of a string. And then, using case-of to handle `Just` and `Nothing` branch. I think it's not able to cope this situation with `Monad` behavior of `Maybe`, because I don't want to stop computation when `Nothing` got out, I want to handle `Nothing` case. Is there better way to write `getUnionFromString` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `Control.Applicative.<|>` to simplify the logic of trying a different expression if one evaluates to `Nothing`:

```hs
Prelude> import Control.Applicative
Prelude Control.Applicative> Just 1 <|> Nothing
Just 1
Prelude Control.Applicative> Just 1 <|> Just 2
Just 1
Prelude Control.Applicative> Nothing <|> Just 1
Just 1
Prelude Control.Applicative> Nothing <|> Nothing
Nothing
```

Using this along with `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`, we can simplify the code to:

```hs
getUnionFromString :: String -> Union
getUnionFromString str = fromMaybe (S str) $ (I <$> readMaybe str) <|> (F <$> readMaybe str)
```

Haskell's type inference is able to figure out that the first `readMaybe` wants a `Maybe Int` and the second one wants `Maybe Float`, without us explicitly asking for it.

Full code:

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Text.Read

data Union = F Float | I Int | S String

getUnionFromString :: String -> Union
getUnionFromString str = fromMaybe (S str) $ (I <$> readMaybe str) <|> (F <$> readMaybe str)

getStr (F f) = "Float " ++ show f
getStr (I i) = "Int " ++ show i
getStr (S s) = "String " ++ s

main = do
  str <- getLine
  putStrLn $ getStr (getUnionFromString str)
```

Comment: Just for fun I tried creating an `orElse` operator that can tie well with `<|>` chaining:
`(<?>) = flip fromMaybe` so one can write 
`(I <$> readMaybe str) <|> (F <$> readMaybe str) <?> S str` with the default case at the end, it is just an `orElse` in operator form.
In order for this to work the precedence of `<?>` should be `infixr 0 <?>`